# Same property ie used twice in 'In condition' generate wrong SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

[image]

```
from CardAssignInfo a left join a.card.detailSet d
where d.category.system.systemId = :systemId and a.personId is not null
and (a.state.id in (:destroyStateIds) or (a.state.id in (:returnStateIds) and d.category.reuseable = true))
```

this HQL will generate SQL somewhat like:

```
 ........... something.stateId in () or (something.stateId in (:destroyStateIds, :returnStateIds) and ......)
```

The parameter are injected into the same place of SQL in condition, left another place with null condition.

I wonder is it hibernate's specification to have this behavior?

Comment: This looks like an honest bug in Hibernate. Try upgrading to the latest version, and search their bug database for help.